# Generating IDs for pie-like wedges (geometry) in PostgreSQL/PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a query that generates 12 sections (pie-like wedges) in a circle (buffer) of 50 meters around point layer.

```
With buffer as(
SELECT gid as pt_id, (ST_DumpPoints(ST_Buffer(geom,50,3))).geom as geom
FROM my_point_table group by gid, geom
UNION ALL 
SELECT gid as pt_id, geom FROM my_point_table
) 
SELECT gid, (ST_Dump(ST_DelaunayTriangles(ST_Collect(geom),0, 0))).geom geom
FROM buffer
GROUP BY pt_id
```

I would like to assign IDs to these sections like this:

[image: assigning IDs to circle pie-like wedges]

Suggestions on how to do this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: belongs on [gis.se]

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I may ask it there.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
With my_point_table as (
    select 1 as gid, 'POINT(0 0)'::geometry as geom
    union
    select 2 as gid, 'POINT(1 1)'::geometry as geom
), buffer as(
    SELECT gid as pt_id, (ST_DumpPoints(ST_Buffer(geom,50,3))).geom as geom
    FROM my_point_table group by gid, geom
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT gid as pt_id, geom FROM my_point_table
) , tr as (
    SELECT pt_id, (ST_Dump(ST_DelaunayTriangles(ST_Collect(geom),0, 0))).geom geom
    FROM buffer
    GROUP BY pt_id
)
select row_number() OVER (partition by pt_id), pt_id, geom from tr
```

First part is to mock your "my_point_table" table.

row_number() OVER (partition by pt_id)
is what generates a sequential number for each feature.

Comment: Well thanks a lot. It was helpful but didn't give the result as expected. I tried with both mock point and my own point layer. IDs were in sequence from 1 to 6 and then 12, 11, 7, 8, 9, 10. Any idea whats happening?